# Place a component to middle right in React Native

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I am still learning about react native especially flexbox. So I have a TouchableOpacity that have some child components on it, like this:

[image]

And the problem is I can't move that arrow icon to the middle right of TouchableOpacity. I try with 
`justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'flex-end'` But nothing happened. Here is my code :

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onRowPress}>
<View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
    <CardSection style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Icons name="monitor" size={50} style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }} />
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <Text style={styles.channelStyle}>
                {item.nama}
            </Text>
            <Text
                style={
                    [item.status === 'Online' ? onlineTextStyle : offlineTextStyle]
                }
            >
                {item.status}
            </Text>
        </View>
        <Icons name="arrow-right" size={50} style={styles.arrowIconStyle} />
    </CardSection>
</View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

And this is the style:

```
const styles = {
channelStyle: {
    fontSize: 25,
    paddingLeft: 30
},
onlineTextStyle: {
    paddingLeft: 30,
    color: 'green'
},
offlineTextStyle: {
    paddingLeft: 30,
    color: 'red'
},
footerTextStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#fff',
    padding: 5,
    fontSize: 18
},
arrowIconStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'flex-end'
}
};
```

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try the following and let me know how it goes?

```
// 1. Add flexDirection row here.
<CardSection style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>

    ...code...

    // 2. Add alignSelf here.
    <Icons name="arrow-right" size={50} style={[styles.arrowIconStyle, {alignSelf: 'flex-end'}]} />
</CardSection>
```

If that doesn't work, try not doing the previous step 2 and instead try this.

```
...code...
<Icons name="arrow-right" size={50} style={styles.arrowIconStyle} />

const styles = {
  ...code...
  arrowIconStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'flex-end'
  }
};
```

## Update

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onRowPress}>
  <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
    <CardSection style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Icons name="monitor" size={50} style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }} />
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
          <Text style={styles.channelStyle}>
            {item.nama}
          </Text>
          <Text
          style={[item.status === 'Online' ? onlineTextStyle : offlineTextStyle]}>
            {item.status}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>

      <Icons name="arrow-right" size={50} style={styles.arrowIconStyle} />
    </CardSection>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: nothing happened :( 
but i appreciate for your help.

Comment: Wow it worked.. Thank you very much, you saved my day